# Retrieve target element in CodeAccessSecurityAttribute

Tags: c#, security, attributes

I realize you can't get the target entity in the Attribute itself, but what about in an associated Permission object when using a CodeAccessSecurityAttribute?  The Permission object gets called at runtime so it seems there should be a way but I'm at a loss.

```
public sealed class MySecurityAttribute : CodeAccessSecurityAttribute
{
    public override IPermission CreatePermission()
    {
        MySecurityPermission permission = new MySecurityPermission();

        //set its properties
        permission.Name = this.Name;
        permission.Unrestricted = this.Unrestricted;
        return permission;
    }

}

public class MySecurityPermission : IPermission, IUnrestrictedPermission
{

    public MySecurityPermission(PermissionState state)
    {
           // what method was the attribute decorating that
           // created this MySecurityPermission?
    }

    public void Demand()
    {
           // Or here?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about walking the call stack? At least that would narrow down what you need to reflect over. Grab [System.Diagnostics.StackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.aspx) and use [GetFrame](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stackframe.getmethod.aspx) to get the stack frame one step up from where you are.

It's rather nasty though - CAS attributes really, in my opinion, shouldn't be conditional on what was decorated, rather they should depend on the conditions set in their parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess you could use reflection to scan through all the loaded assemblies, looking for any class/member that has `this` as an attribute.  It'd be quite slow, though, so it's not something you'd want to do often, or in a large project.

Comment: Yup, that's the only solution I could come up with as well but reflection isn't an option given the project size, and frequency it would need to occur.  Thanks for the feedback though.